# Json to jqplot chart

Tags: php, json, jqplot

i try to make charts with jqplot from JSON format.

file.txt contains:

```
   [[["2008-09-30 4:00PM",15],["2008-10-30 4:00PM",8],["2008-11-30 4:00PM",17],["2008-12-30 4:00PM",10]]]
```

in jqplot:

```
<script class="code" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Our ajax data renderer which here retrieves a text file.
  // it could contact any source and pull data, however.
  // The options argument isn't used in this renderer.
  var ajaxDataRenderer = function(url, plot, options) {
    var ret = null;
    $.ajax({
      // have to use synchronous here, else the function 
      // will return before the data is fetched
      async: false,
      url: url,
      dataType:"json",
      success: function(data) {
        ret = data;
      }, error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
      alert(xhr.responseText);}
    });
    return ret;
  };

  // The url for our json data
  var jsonurl = "file.txt";

  // passing in the url string as the jqPlot data argument is a handy
  // shortcut for our renderer.  You could also have used the
  // "dataRendererOptions" option to pass in the url.
  var plot2 = $.jqplot('chart2', jsonurl,{
    title: "AJAX JSON Data Renderer",
    dataRenderer: ajaxDataRenderer,
    dataRendererOptions: {
      unusedOptionalUrl: jsonurl
    }

  });
});
</script>
```

when i run this code i got an empty chart like that:
[image]

haw can i fix this ? and how we define axis x = date and y=value ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the data does not "arrive" to the plot.

I assume you are on a Linux\UNIX based server: Change `"file.txt"` to `"./file.txt"` to [correctly access](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4430/why-do-we-use-to-execute-a-file) the file in the current folder.

For rendering the `x-axis` with Date Renderer, refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15378723/jqplot-with-dateaxisrenderer-and-ajax).